# How to turn off viewport to orthographic snapping during rotation on alt + middle mouse drag?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut

**That was view axis. Can be closed.**

Settings: I made factory reset and turned on emulate 3 button mouse.
Completely clean Blender without anything changed still has this
feature...

**Issue**: I want to turn off Blender behavior: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ Middle mouse
button drag, which is causing the viewport to snap to front/top/left/right
orthographic view. I don't want this snapping feature.

And it seems it can't be turned off ([Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhoiW.jpg)) 3D View -> Rotate View -> View3D Rotate Modal, changing, disabling or clicking X doesn't change anything so it's maybe not this one setting

[image: Image 1]

Changing Rotate View - and picking <kbd>Alt</kbd> key ([Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSxRw.jpg)) changes normal rotation of viewport to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + middle mouse and this snapping feature to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + left mouse button (I'm using emulate 3 button mouse).

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to solve it. Turn off View Axis. 
[image]

Comment: Not sure why this is on by default. Blender devs should default this to off.

Answer (score 0):

In More recent versions of blender, this can be found in the View3D Rotate Modal. Go in there and turn off axis snap as detailed below:

[image]